# Set two root nodes for TreeView

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Is there a way to set two root nodes for one TreeView?

I found many example if simple TreeView but there is no useful example for my case.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Did you find a solution for this problem? If yes then kindly provide your solution.

Answer (score 51):

No: a tree only has one root node.

To get the effect you want, create a dummy root node and add your two nodes to it. Create the TreeView with the dummy root node and call `tree.setShowRoot(false)`, so the dummy node does not appear.

```
final TreeItem<String> root1 = new TreeItem<>("root 1");
final TreeItem<String> root2 = new TreeItem<>("root 2");
final TreeView<String> tree = createTreeView(root1, root2);

// ...

private TreeView<String> createTreeView(TreeItem<String> root1, TreeItem<String> root2) {
    TreeItem<String> dummyRoot = new TreeItem<>();
    dummyRoot.getChildren().addAll(root1, root2);
    TreeView<String> tree = new TreeView<>(dummyRoot);
    tree.setShowRoot(false);
    return tree ;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is a possible solution. But later it will make the code very complex. Is there any alternative solution?

Comment: yes, I made that exactly. So now, I'm wondering, is possible to set a separation between that exactly 2 nodes in the treeview?or for it I should maintain the data in 2 treeviews?

Comment: Found this answer today , wow James_D you saved my life again ! :)